# error when update data to database using checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to update my database using checkbox, when i delete data, my code is work. but when i update to add some value to database, i got some error.

**
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'HotelRoomFacility' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
**

this my code

my service

```
public void UpdateFacilityInHotel(List<int> FacilityIDs, int RoomTypeID)
        {
            List<HotelRoomFacility> hotelRoomFacilities = _HotelRoomFacility.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.RoomTypeID == RoomTypeID).ToList();
            foreach (int newFacility in FacilityIDs)
            {
                if (hotelRoomFacilities.Where(h => h.RoomFacilityID == newFacility).Count() == 0)
                {
                    HotelRoomFacility facility = new HotelRoomFacility
                    {
                        RoomFacilityID = newFacility,
                        RoomTypeID = RoomTypeID
                    };
                    _HotelRoomFacility.Add(facility);
                }
            }
            foreach (HotelRoomFacility facility in hotelRoomFacilities)
            {
                if (FacilityIDs.Contains(facility.RoomFacilityID) == false)
                    _HotelRoomFacility.Delete(facility);
            }
            _HotelFacilityRepository.CommitChanges();
        }
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult EditRoom(int RoomTypeID)
        {
            ViewBag.hotel = _hotelService.GetByID(_HotelID).HotelName;
            //var roomType = _hotelService.ShowRoomByID(RoomTypeID);
            //return View(roomType);

            List<EditRoomTypeViewModel> editRoomTypeViewModel = _showRoomByIDService.ShowRoomByID(RoomTypeID);
            return View(editRoomTypeViewModel.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditRoom(EditRoomTypeViewModel typeRoom, FormCollection forms)
        {
            List<string> IDs = forms["FacilityIDs"].Split(',').ToList();

            List<int> FacilityIDs = new List<int>();

            foreach (string ID in IDs)
            {
                FacilityIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ID));
            }

            _showRoomByIDService.UpdateFacilityInHotel(FacilityIDs, _HotelID);


            return EditRoom(_HotelID);

            var x = _hotelService.UpdateRoom(typeRoom.RoomTypeID, typeRoom.RoomTypeName, typeRoom.RoomTypeDescription);

            if (x != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Room");
            }
            return View(typeRoom);
        }
```

my view

```
@model XNet.Repository.Model.EditRoomTypeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "addRoom";
}

<h2>Edit Room</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Isikan Data</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("Hotel Name")
        </div>
        <div>
           @ViewBag.hotel
        </div>
        <br />

        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoomTypeID)
        </div>
        <br />


        <div>
            @Html.Label("Room Type Name")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
        </div>
        <br />

        <div>
            @Html.Label("Room Type Description")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RoomTypeDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomTypeDescription)
        </div>
        <br />

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Facility Name</th>
                <th> is available</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var facility in Model.facilitiesInRoom)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @(facility.RoomFacilityName)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;">
                        <input type="checkbox" @(facility.RoomFacilityAvailable ? " checked=checked" : null) name="FacilityIDs" value="@facility.RoomFacilityID" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>       

<br />


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            <input style="width:100px;" type="button" title="EditHotelDetail" value="Back to Detail"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Hotel")    '" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is the database diagram

[image]

Comment: What's the primary key of HotelRoomFacility? RoomFacilityID ?

Comment: not RoomFacilityIDm but HotelRoomFacilityID is primary key

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on line _HotelRoomFacility.Add(facility); and tell me what's  facility's HotelRoomFacilityID at that point? The error tells you that somewhere in the code you are assigning a value to HotelRoomFacilityID before adding it to the database.

Comment: hotelRoomFacilityID is 2.... i still dont understand...